# Watermarking dynamically created pdf's in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans6.8

How can we watermark dynamically created pdf's in google app engine using Java/Netbeans? 
GAE does not support `FileOutputStream`. I tried PdfStamper but it doesn't support `FileOutputStream`. servlet code is below

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
        String fileName="abc.pdf";
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());

```
            document.open();
            try {
                 Paragraph title1 = new Paragraph("Chapter 1", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER_OBLIQUE, 18, Font.BOLDITALIC, new CMYKColor(0, 255, 255,17)));
                    document.add(title1);
                    document.add(new Paragraph("Hi Namita, welcome to pdf generation"));
                    document.add(new Paragraph("Here we are creating pdf of records"));
                    document.add(new Paragraph("Please save records"));
          } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
             document.close();
}
```

Comment: Are you already creating the PDFs somehow and your problem is on how to watermark them?!

Comment: i am creating pdf using response.getOutputStream. When i run this servlet, it creates pdf and shows dialog to download it. Now I just wants to watermark before it ask to download. Is it possible?   plz help soon... thanks

Comment: Yup....    I got perfect solution of my query on link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374006/add-page-number-to-pdf-using-pdfstamperitext?rq=1                                             Thanks

Comment: So if you got your solution.. you could delete this questions then, as it's not adding anything to SO..